# Editing the CSS in react range slider from npm module

Tags: reactjs, rangeslider

I want to change the background-color of React RangeSlider. Since its library is installed via npm, I cannot edit the CSS. Is there any way to import CSS from npm module and use it as my customized CSS. This is the  code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-rangeslider'
class Horizontal extends Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.state = {
            value: 850
        }
    }
    handleChangeStart = () => {
        console.log('Change event started')
    };
    handleChange = value => {
        this.setState({
            value: value
        })
    };

    handleChangeComplete = () => {
        console.log('Change event completed')
    };
    render () {
        const { value } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='slider'  style={{ marginTop:'165px',marginLeft:'319px',width:'700px',backgroundColor:'EF5350'}} >

                    <div style={{ textAlign:'center',color:'gray',fontSize:'35px',marginBottom:'82px'}}>
                        <p> What is the size of your property?</p>
                    </div>
                    <Slider
                        min={850}
                        max={5000}
                        value={value}
                        onChangeStart={this.handleChangeStart}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
                    />
                    <div className='value'>{value}</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Horizontal
```

I have taken this code [from this site](https://whoisandy.github.io/react-rangeslider/)

The slider shows up after I used this in the header section

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-rangeslider/umd/rangeslider.min.css" />
```

Otherwise, the slider doesn't show up even though I installed the library. It's not even overwriting the CSS.

Comment: not yet.you seemed to use the whole code including the library.I tried to override the  css in my code.It still remains same.

Comment: You should use the whole code including the library and then try to override the CSS. That's the way to do it. You should check whether the custom CSS is applied or not by visiting the class `rangeslider__fill` in the DOM in devTools

Comment: I have installed the library.The slider does not show up until i add the link stylesheet in header section.Its not even overwritng

Comment: where do you override the CSS though lets assume i want to add `className='custom'` that will change the fill color so my css will be something like this `.custom .rangeslider-horizontal .rangeslider__fill { background-color: #1e88e5 }` but then where do i add this to the index.css that came with the slider? i tried that and didn't work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overrride the CSS responsible for the background color.

Like this:

```
.rangeslider-horizontal .rangeslider__fill {
  background-color: #1e88e5
}
```

Where `rangeslider__fill` is the class of main part of the slider.

Here's a [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-react-rangeslider-example-5vb5r)

Comment: where do you override the CSS though lets assume i want to add className='custom' that will change the fill color so my css will be something like this 
.custom .rangeslider-horizontal .rangeslider__fill {
  background-color: #1e88e5
}

but then where do i add this to the index.css that came with the slider? i tried that and didn't work ??